# Character becoming int when sent over socket

Tags: c++, sockets, character-encoding

Ok so I am sending raw data over a socket.

```
unsigned char data [] = {0xFA, 0xDE, 0xDB, 0xAD, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x54, 0x65, 0x61, 0x67,0x61, 0x6E, 0x19, 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x68, 0x6F, 0x77, 0x20, 0x61, 0x72, 0x65, 0x20, 0x79, 0x6F, 0x75, 0x20, 0x66, 0x62, 0x67, 0x67, 0x6F, 0x74, 0x3F };
```

ends up being the same as that.

but when it is being recieved it ends up like this

```
fffffffa ffffffde ffffffdb ffffffad 0 0 0 6 54 65 61 67 61 6e 19 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 68 6f 77 20 61 72 65 20 79 6f 75 20 66 62 67 67 6f 74 3f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

notice how the first 4 bytes in the original change into 16 bytes.

Any idea what is causing that?

A little code

```
char data[512];
if ( socket.Receive(address, data, sizeof(data)) ){
    char *point = data;
    if ( (unsigned int ) *point == 0xFADEDBAD )
            fprintf(stderr, " WIN \n");
```

/////////////////////// THE RECEIVE FUNCTION FROM ABOVE ///////////////////

```
            int Receive( Address & sender, void * data, int size )
            {
                    assert( data );
                    assert( size > 0 );

                    if ( socket == 0 )
                            return false;


                    #if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
                    typedef int socklen_t;
                    #endif

                    sockaddr_in from;
                    socklen_t fromLength = sizeof( from );

                    int received_bytes = recvfrom( socket, (char*)data, size, 0, (sockaddr*)&from, &fromLength );

                    if ( received_bytes <= 0 )
                            return 0;

                    unsigned int address = ntohl( from.sin_addr.s_addr );
                    unsigned int port = ntohs( from.sin_port );

                    sender = Address( address, port );

                    return received_bytes;
            }

    private:

            int socket;
    };
```

}

//////// HOW THE DATA IS BEING SENT //////////////////

```
unsigned char data [] = {0xFA, 0xDE, 0xDB, 0xAD, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x54, 0x65, 0x61, 0x67,0x61, 0x6E, 0x19, 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x68, 0x6F, 0x77, 0x20, 0x61, 0x72, 0x65, 0x20, 0x79, 0x6F, 0x75, 0x20, 0x66, 0x61, 0x67, 0x67, 0x6F, 0x74, 0x3F };

socket.Send (address, (char*)data, sizeof (data)  );
```

//////////////// METHOD ////////////////

```
 bool Send( const Address & destination, const void * data, int size )
            {
                    assert( data );
                    assert( size > 0 );

                    if ( socket == 0 )
                            return false;

                    sockaddr_in address;
                    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
                    address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( destination.GetAddress() );
                    address.sin_port = htons( (unsigned short) destination.GetPort() );

                    int sent_bytes = sendto( socket, (const char*)data, size, 0, (sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(sockaddr_in) );

                    return sent_bytes == size;
            }
```

Comment: how are you writing the bytes? can you post a snippet of the code?

Comment: Just a guess: The fifth char are null. maybe terminates your array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the socket that's converting characters to int, it's you when you receive them into signed (! you're not declaring data unsigned !) characters. You don't show the part where you output the "bad" hex values, but i assume it's something like

```
printf("%02x", data[i])
```

which takes the (signed!) character in data[i], converts it to a 4 byte integer (which may have a value between -128 and 127, 0xffffff80 to 0x0000007f in hex), then output that integer.

Declaring "unsigned char data[512]" on the receiving side would fix that.

Also, your

```
if ( (unsigned int ) *point == 0xFADEDBAD )
```

is wrong, it should read

```
if ( *(unsigned int *) point == 0xFADEDBAD )
```

You don't what to use *point to access a (1-byte) character, then convert this character to int; you want to to convert the pointer to a pointer that points to 4 bytes integer, then access these 4 bytes through the pointer.

Depending on your hardware, you might still run into trouble with endianness and alignment, though. Google for those terms if you don't know about them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Missed the signed char and that was me being retarded XD we all have our moments.

Comment: Assuming little endian that comparison won't be true as type punning like that will give you `0xaddbdefa`.